# Moving a UIImageView along UIBezierPath with CAKeyframeAnimation does nothing

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to move a `UIImageView` along a `UIBezierPath` by using `CAKeyframeAnimation` in this function. Currently it doesn't move at all. I know the path creation is right because I'm drawing it to check and it's a nice arc in the shape I want.

Code:

```
func animateSun() {
    let sunImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Sun"))
    sunImageView.sizeToFit()

    let sunAnimationPath = UIBezierPath()
    let pathStart = CGPoint(x: (sunImageView.frame.width / 2), y: self.view.frame.height - (self.rearMountainView.frame.height / 2) + sunImageView.frame.height)
    let pathEnd = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - (sunImageView.frame.width / 2), y: self.view.frame.height - (self.rearMountainView.frame.height / 2) + (sunImageView.frame.height))

    sunAnimationPath.moveToPoint(pathStart)

    let controlOne = CGPoint(x: pathStart.x, y: pathStart.y - 500)
    let controlTwo = CGPoint(x: pathEnd.x, y: pathEnd.y - 500)

    sunAnimationPath.addCurveToPoint(pathEnd, controlPoint1: controlOne, controlPoint2: controlTwo)

    sunImageView.frame = CGRectMake(pathStart.x - (sunImageView.frame.width / 2), pathStart.y - (sunImageView.frame.height / 2), sunImageView.frame.width, sunImageView.frame.height)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "day")
    animation.duration = 15
    animation.repeatCount = 0
    animation.path = sunAnimationPath.CGPath
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false

    sunImageView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "day")
    self.view.addSubview(sunImageView)
    //self.view.sendSubviewToBack(sunImageView)

    let layer          = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path          = sunAnimationPath.CGPath
    layer.strokeColor   = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.lineWidth     = 1.0
    layer.fillColor     = nil

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how you create you animation is wrong, the key should be equal `position`, because you want to animate `position` property, not a `day` property. Also, for example, it could be `position.x` or `position.y`, these are animatable properties. Change "day" key to "position" and animation will work:

```
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
```

From documentation about `CAKeyframeAnimation`:

> Creates and returns an CAPropertyAnimation instance for the specified
>   key path. A new instance of CAPropertyAnimation with the key path set
>   to keyPath.
>   Parameters: keyPath - The key path of the property to be animated.